# Dúvida, query não funciona exatamente como quero... PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados chamada `emails`, com os seguintes campos:

```
id
subject
body
e status (0, para não enviado, ou 1, para enviado).
```

Eu estava fazendo uma *query* para recuperar somente as linhas que possuem status 1, a minha *query* SQL foi:

```
"SELECT * FROM emails WHERE status = '1'"
```

O problema é... Fazendo através de consulta parametrizada,

```
$status = "1";

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE status = :status");
$stmt->bindParam(":status", $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

No fim quero que ele me retorne todos os emails que se encontram com esse status igual a 1, não apenas a primeira ocorrência, nem o numero das linhas afetadas pela *query*, até agora não consegui, pois ou só me retorna a primeira ocorrência usando `$stmt->fetch();` ou então o numero de linhas afetadas usando `$stmt->rowCount();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o método `fetchAll`:

```
$contents = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Bem simples rs e Funcionou... Muito obrigado ;)